# Is there an indent option for jslint or has it been removed?

Tags: javascript, syntax, whitespace, lint, jslint

The indent option appears to not be recognized any more.

http://linterrors.com/js/option-indent

Is this still an option for jslint or has it been removed?

I've tried setting it using the web interface [here](https://www.jslint.com/), in multiple syntaxes, but I keep getting an error.

> Bad option 'indent'.

```
/*jslint
    bitwise,
    browser:true,
    indent: 2
*/

function test () {
  const test = "hello SO";
}
```

**Research:**

The changelog on [github](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) seems pretty small and does not mention it.

Comment: It must have been removed, because any time someone proposed to add it again, the author replied with _"No thank you."_ ([here](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/pull/153#issuecomment-44982346), or [here](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/pull/191#issuecomment-237415385)). If you want something more customizable, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) provides tons of options, that's the one I use

Comment: Read both, but still seem ambiguous.

Comment: It's been [removed in 2015 in this commit](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/commit/557afd32bcaa35480d31a86f02d3a8c06a4e5b5c#diff-4822639e8179a5188bdfd8cfb48d9e103a7dcc1f2b1036465ab7017d4166c2a8L545) (open the diff for the `jslint.js` file and look for "indent"). Here are the [allowed options as of now](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/blob/beta/jslint.js#L144), and `indent` is not part of it. There is now another: `white`, which is just a Boolean to accept whitespace instead of tabs, but that disables the indentation checks

Comment: thx for help.   how exactly did you find this information?  I can't discern anything from those two links.  I simply looked in the changelog and found nothing relevant - update added to Question.  How did you know what to look for outside the changelog?  Can you break down your process?

Comment: Humans make mistakes, and forget to do things sometimes. When documentation is written manually (that applies to changelogs too), it's not linked in any way to the actual code behind it. The author has to remember to reflect the changes in the docs. The source code is the only reference that you can be sure is up-to-date. That's why a good practice is to auto-generate docs from the code and not write it manually. And to generate changelogs based on commit messages. So any time something isn't clear to me from the docs, I just look at the code

Comment: You can see the most recent set of directives currently at [jslint.com](http://jslint.com). `indent2` is listed and described in the sample code that's shown in the textbox. It is a shame [the whitespace section in the docs](https://www.jslint.com/help.html#new) doesn't mention it, though it does talk about using 4 space indent. You can tell he has edited it recently, as the Whitespace header tags don't have an `id` atm (I linked to `#new`, just above it) & it's a beta. That said, Crockford seems to expect you to read his code, which is, admittedly, well-written and [perhaps overly] commented.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: [jslint](https://www.jslint.com/) recently added 2-space indent support with directive `/*jslint indent2*/`

i'm a [jslint](https://www.jslint.com/) maintainer.  toyed with a patch reintroducing directive `/*jslint indent2*/` to make jslint more accessible to projects already using 2-space indents [here](https://github.com/kaizhu256/jslint/commit/c9e0f9fb2dd14d71c0fce1272c89cff9b2abf368).

you can post a feature-request for it @ https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint/issues to speed up the process.

latest jslint has the following directives:

```js
// Optional directives.
// .... /*jslint beta*/ .......... Enable experimental features.
// .... /*jslint bitwise*/ ....... Allow bitwise operators.
// .... /*jslint browser*/ ....... Assume browser environment.
// .... /*jslint convert*/ ....... Allow conversion operators.
// .... /*jslint couch*/ ......... Assume CouchDb environment.
// .... /*jslint debug*/ ......... Include jslint stack-trace in warnings.
// .... /*jslint devel*/ ......... Allow console.log() and friends.
// .... /*jslint eval*/ .......... Allow eval().
// .... /*jslint for*/ ........... Allow for-statement.
// .... /*jslint getset*/ ........ Allow get() and set().
// .... /*jslint long*/ .......... Allow long-lines.
// .... /*jslint name*/ .......... Allow weird property-names.
// .... /*jslint node*/ .......... Assume Node.js environment.
// .... /*jslint single*/ ........ Allow single-quote strings.
// .... /*jslint test_internal_error*/ ... Test jslint's internal-error
// ........................................... handling-ability.
// .... /*jslint this*/ .......... Allow 'this'.
// .... /*jslint unordered*/ ..... Allow unordered cases, params, properties.
// .... /*jslint variable*/ ...... Allow unordered const and let declarations
// ................................... that are not at top of function-scope.
// .... /*jslint white: true...... Allow messy whitespace.
```